# Upgrade Magento 2.3.0 to 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I want to upgrade my Magento store from 2.3.0 to 2.3.2.
I am doing the upgrade thing for the first time. 
Can anyone please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run following commands

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.2 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/cache/
rm -rf var/page_cache/
rm -rf var/generation/
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

For more details: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Answer (score 2):

Run below commands from the terminal to upgrade Magento to 2.3.2

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.2 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/cache/
rm -rf var/page_cache/
rm -rf var/generation/
chmod +x bin/magento
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Answer (score 2):

**You Can Upgrade Via Admin As Well,**

[Start System Upgrade](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/upgrader/upgrade-start.html)

> **Setp 1 :-** Save a backup for `composer.json` because the following steps will overwrite it. The commands are as below:
>
> ```
> 1. cd <your Magento install dir>
> 2. cp composer.json composer.json.old
> ```
>
> **Step 2 :-** `php bin/magento maintenance:enable`
>
> **Step 3 :-** `composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.1 --no-update`
>
> **Step 4 :-** `composer update`
>
> **Step 5 :-** `rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs pub/static/deployed_version.txt var/cache
>   var/page_cache var/generation var/view_preprocessed var/session
>   generated/code`
>
> **Step 6 :-** `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
>
> **Step 7 :-** `php bin/magento s:s:d -f`
>
> **Step 8 :-** `php bin/magento maintenance:disable`

For More Details [Command-line upgrade](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html)

Comment: What username and password i need to enter when i run step 3?

Comment: you can get credential on  login this site https://marketplace.magento.com/

Comment: for mor details check this link https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html

Comment: I need to enter public key and secret key?

Comment: yes.............

Comment: upgraded or not ?

Comment: Rathod. YEs done. thank you.

Comment: oky most welcome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98889/discussion-between-nafisa-and-rk-rathod).

Comment: ......I am having one doubt

Comment: yes ..........................

Comment: In my composer.json file it still shows "version": "2.3.0". Howeever, "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.2" . Is this correct?